# Power Query Opens Source Data and Then Can't Access It

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access, power-query

Full disclosure, I'm kinda new to Power Query but I'm running into some weird problems. I'm used to using Data Connections in older versions of Microsoft Office to connect an Access database with an Excel spreadsheet, and having to switch to Power Query has been giving me no small amount of frustration.

I have five queries pulling data from a database, but when I try to refresh them, I run into the error, "[DataFormat.Error] Could not use "xxxxx.accdb"; file already in use." But the file isn't in use. The database is closed.

If I try to refresh the queries individually, they all refresh with no problems. But if I use Refresh All, one or two will refresh while the others will error out. It's as if the queries ***themselves*** are what is using the file and blocking other queries from refreshing from it.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it? I'm at my wit's end and wish I could just go back to Data Connections, which never once gave me a problem like this.

Comment: Try disabling parallel queries when using an access db: in Options > Current File > Data Load > uncheck "Enable parallel loading of tables"

Comment: If you use this DB source a lot then I also recommend checking out using the Dataverse connector in Access, so that Dataverse is your source for Power BI. It smooths out a lot of the Access/PQ jank, but really depends on your use case